# get physical disk name for a file

Tags: windows-server-2008, files, diskmanagement

When I opened disk management in Windows Server 2008 I see

```
Disk  8 G: H: 
Disk  9 H:
Disk 10 H: I
```

Now, I have few files in H: drive and I want to know which disk it belongs to. I have to do it because few files in H: have low IO and I want to move them to other Disk.

I am completely newbie to Windows management so let me know if I need to provide more information or my question is not properly formed.

Comment: According to your question, volume H: is on disks 8, 9 and 10... so there you go.

Comment: *Ha ha ha*, I did not realize this until after I posted a PowerShell snippet. Anyway, I'll leave it there.

Comment: @Joeqwerty & Daniel What I meant that I have few files in H: drive and I want to know which file belongs to which disk. That file could be in disk 8 or 9 or 10.

Answer (score 3):

This snippet prints the disk on which volume "H" is located.
`Get-Partition -DriveLetter H | Get-Disk | Format-List`

---

### Edit

Having a second look at your question I think I see a spanned volume over three dynamic disks. In this case it won't be so easy to locate the disk a file is on. And even if you know this information, it will be impossible to store the file on a different disk within the same volume, without specialised software and the risk of breaking the file system.

Since you are originally asking because of your low I/O, let me give you a different path to the solution.

Use a hardware RAID controller and create a proper hardware RAID and place your files on that. Scrap the dynamic disks and the spanned volume. I advise to consult a professional, as this might be a little to big for a "completely newbie to Windows management". (No offense)

Comment: Thanks for your answer +1 for the advice. Actually, I have few data files in H drive, and only few of them having a low I/O. So, I suspect that those files belong to a disk whose I/O is low. Now, I am not  sure whether it is Disk 8, 9 or 10. If I can get the Disk name from the file then it would be easier for me to track.